# how to handle error while rendering component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

Let's say I have a child component

```
function MainContent(prop) {
  return (
    <main>
      <p>{prop.message.message.substring(1, 5)}</p>
    </main>
  );
}
```

and rendering it in parent like

```
function App() {
  const data = [
    {
      message: 'first message',
    },
    {
      message: 'second message',
    },
    {
      //message: 'third message', working
      wrongkey: 'third message', // not working
    },
  ];
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      {data && data.map((item) => <MainContent message={item} />)}

      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Let's say if there is any wrong data and one of the child component inside the loop gets error then the whole page errors,

what I want to avoid whole page error just to show a message of that place of child component where the error occurred.

This is just a sample what I am trying to achieve, I know I can handle  error of a key like below

```
{prop.message.message?.substring(1, 5)}
```

But with actual data, we cannot be sure where error may occur.

[sample code link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-parent-child-component-i4tc25?file=src/MainContent.js)

I am using Typescript in my project

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional operator and show error in case the data is missing:

```
function MainContent(prop) {
  return (
    <main>
      <p>{
        prop.message.message
        ? prop.message.message?.substring(1, 5)
        : "Error text"
      }
      </p>
    </main>
  );
}
```

Comment: I already mention I can do that, but thing is if the json is lengthy and complex we cannot do it for every keys